# Split a column into multiple rows

Tags: oracle

I have data like this my table:

| Year | Month | Daytype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "2020" | "01" | "HBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBB" |
| "2020" | "02" | "BBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBB" |

Now I need to convert this table as below ;

| Year | Month | Day | Daytype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 01 | 01 | H |
| 2020 | 01 | 02 | B |
| 2020 | 01 | 03 | B |
| 2020 | 01 | 04 | B |
| 2020 | 01 | 05 | B |
| 2020 | 01 | 06 | H |
| 2020 | 01 | 07 | H |

I tried option using regular expression. but my problem the daytype string doesn't have any delimiter string.

Can someone assist me. I want this in SQL only

Comment: Could you edit the question to show what you tried and how do you want it to be done? Something like shell scripting works? or do you want it as pure SQL?

Comment: Shouldn't February 2020 have 29 days?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive query and simple string functions (which are much faster than regular expressions):

```sql
WITH days (year, month, daytypes, day, daytype) AS (
  SELECT year, month, daytype, 1, SUBSTR(daytype, 1, 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT year, month, daytypes, day + 1, SUBSTR(daytypes, day + 1, 1)
  FROM   days
  WHERE  day < LENGTH(daytypes)
)
SELECT year, month, day, daytype
FROM   days
ORDER BY year, month, day;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Year,Month,Daytype) AS
SELECT 2020, 1, 'HBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020, 2, 'BBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBBBBHHBBB' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | DAYTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 5 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 6 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 7 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 8 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 9 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 10 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 11 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 12 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 13 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 14 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 15 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 16 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 17 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 18 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 19 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 20 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 21 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 22 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 23 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 24 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 25 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 26 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 27 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 28 | H |
| 2020 | 1 | 29 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 30 | B |
| 2020 | 1 | 31 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 3 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 4 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 5 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 6 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 7 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 8 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 9 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 10 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 11 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 12 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 13 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 14 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 15 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 16 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 17 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 18 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 19 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 20 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 21 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 22 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 23 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 24 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 25 | H |
| 2020 | 2 | 26 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 27 | B |
| 2020 | 2 | 28 | B |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O0uSF0-G)

Comment: in this how we can find third business day of each month.like for feb the third businessday is 2020-02-05

Comment: @Satya If you have a different (follow-up) question that is outside the scope of your original question then you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather than trying to expand the scope of your existing question in comments.